# Showing that $\frac{1}{f}$ is is analytic in some open set containing $\overline{B(0,1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is analytic in the disk $B(0,2)$ of radius $2$ centered at the origin, and satisfies $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in \overline{B(0,1)}$, how do we show that there exists an open set $U$ containing $\overline{B(0,1)}$ such that the function $1/f$ is analytic in $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(z) \ne 0$ for $|z|=1$. Then around each point $z \in \partial B(0,1)$, there is a neighbourhood $U_z=B(z, r_z) (r_z>0)$ such that $U_z \in B(0,2)$ and $f$ is non-vanishing in $U_z$. Since $\partial B(0,1)$ is compact and $\{U_z\}_{z \in \partial B(0,1)}$ is an open cover, thus there is a finite subcover, say, $U(z_1, r_1) \cup \dotsc \cup U(z_n, r_n)$. One can then choose small enough $r$ such that $\overline{B(0,1)} \subset B(0, r) \subset B(0,2)$. Moreover, $f$ is non-vanishing on $B(0,r)$.

Alternatively, let if possible, there be no such $U$. Then every open ball $B(0, 1+1/n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (containing $\overline{B(0,1)}$) must contain a zero, say $z_n$, of $f$. Under given hypothesis, we must have $1<|z_n|<1+1/n$. This way, passing onto a subsequence if necessary, one can construct a bounded sequence, say $\{z_n\}$, such that $f(z_n)=0$ and $|z_n| \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.  Let $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n=z$. Then $|z|=1$ and using continuity of $f$ on $B(0, 2)$, we get that $f(z_n) \to f(z)$ as $n \to \infty$. Consequently, $f(z)=0$ which is a contradiction.